# Problem installing modules for Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter?

Tags: asus

I need some help please. I am a complete Linux noob and find this pretty difficult stuff. that said, I have followed the above instructions and everything seems OK thru step 6. However, when I try to install the module I get a few lines ok, then:

```
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory. stop
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

[there are 3 *. I don't know why only 1 shows]

how do I get around this.

Comment: What above instructions have you followed? I don't see any, neither above or below. Make sure you have the `linux-headers-generic` package installed, then try the `make` command again.

Comment: Mike, I had originally posted this here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102956/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-n53-wifi-adapter, which shows the steps I took. I'll check and see if I have the Linux-headers-generic package.