# Installing Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter failing

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus, adapter

I tried to install the Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter using the instructions from the "[How do I install an Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102956/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-n53-wifi-adapter)" however is failing with the message below:

```
2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1156:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid();
                    ^
/home/carlos/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1157:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();
                    ^
make[2]: *** [/home/carlos/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/carlos/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Additional information:

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: d4:3d:7e:54:fd:a6
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.2.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c04000-f7c04fff memory:f7c00000-f7c03fff
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12493  1 
udf                    83847  1 
crc_itu_t              12627  1 udf
rfcomm                 53664  0 
bnep                   18895  2 
bluetooth             342208  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            13140  1 
uvcvideo               71309  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
snd_usb_audio         127948  1 
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         39258  1 uvcvideo
snd_usbmidi_lib        24367  1 snd_usb_audio
videodev              108503  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
mxm_wmi                12893  0 
joydev                 17101  0 
hid_topseed            12522  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45440  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    59259  1 
intel_rapl             18301  0 
snd_hda_intel          42730  5 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    13845  0 
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
snd_hda_codec         164067  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
radeon               1420704  1 
snd_hwdep              13272  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  4 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
i915                  709887  3 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               13195  0 
snd_rawmidi            25135  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ttm                    72725  1 radeon
kvm_intel             132620  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         48868  2 i915,radeon
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
parport_pc             31981  1 
kvm                   388270  1 kvm_intel
drm                   244037  7 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,radeon
snd                    60939  25 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12600  1 snd
ppdev                  17391  0 
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
lp                     13299  0 
mei_me                 18195  0 
serio_raw              13230  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13197  2 i915,radeon
mei                    66737  1 mei_me
mac_hid                13037  0 
wmi                    18673  1 mxm_wmi
intel_smartconnect     12555  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
video                  18903  1 i915
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_logitech_dj        18165  0 
usbhid                 47070  0 
hid                    87604  5 hid_topseed,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
usb_storage            48417  1 
ahci                   25579  3 
r8169                  61562  0 
psmouse                91357  0 
libahci                27214  1 ahci
mii                    13654  1 r8169
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0766:0204 Jess-Link Products Co., Ltd TopSpeed Cyberlink Remote Control
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 059b:0475 Iomega Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:179d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N53 802.11abgn Network Adapter [Ralink RT3572]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04b4:6560 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. CY7C65640 USB-2.0 "TetraHub"
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:08ce Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 5000
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`modinfo rt2800usb | grep 179`

```
alias:          usb:v0B05p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*

alias:          usb:v0B05p179Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Does anybody know to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your modinfo result tells us that the default version of the driver rt2800usb covers your device. Let's load it and see if your wireless comes to life:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
iwconfig
```

Do you have a wireless interface, ideally wlan0? Can you click the Network Manager icon and connect? If so, let's get the module to load on boot automatically:

```
sudo -i
echo rt2800usb  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

If loading the module does not help, let's look in the logs to see what went wrong:

```
dmesg | grep rt2
rfkill list all
```

Comment: Thanks chili555, you are the best!! It is working now. I appreciate!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The ASus USB-N53 is now supported with any new install of ubuntu 18, I got the USB-N53 micro working with this package: https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu