# Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter installation under 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I am trying to install the Asus USB-N53 wifi adapter and followed the instructions in 
[How do I install an Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102956/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-n53-wifi-adapter) and [Installing Asus USB-N53 WiFi adapter failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544966/14-04-installing-asus-usb-n53-wifi-adapter-failing)

The wifi adapter does not start using these; iwconfig outputs

> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.

lsusb shows that the device (ASUSTek ...) is connected

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0b05:180b ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17a0:0310 Samson Technologies Corp. Meteor condenser microphone
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046a:0011 Cherry GmbH G83 (RS 6000) Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M500 Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I would be glad for any suggestions on how to proceed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you linked are for a different device, 0b05:**179d** ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N53. You have, instead, 0b05:**180b** ASUSTek Computer, Inc.

Please see: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-N53_B1 where your usb.id is listed. It says: `Probable Linux driver: unknown`

Also see posts #7 through 11 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265150

There is currently no known way to get this device working in any recent version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Don't know about 14.04 mentioned in original question, but for recent ubuntu versions there is a solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654262/missing-driver-for-asus-usb-n53/857086#857086

Answer (score 0):

The ASus USB-N53 is now supported with any new install of ubuntu 18, I got the USB-N53 micro working with this package: https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu