# Problem installing driver Asus USB-N53

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, compiling, asus

I have looked around and I found some answers in similar topics but it didn't work for me.

I tried to install a driver taken from this site http://www.drivers.ga/2015/10/download-driver-asus-usb-n53-b1-n600.html for my USB-N53 Adapter Wireless-N600 from Asus.

Following the instructions in the readme file below :

```
Build Instructions:  
====================

1> tar -jxvf 2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO.tar.bz2
   go to "./2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO" directory.


2> switch to super user.
     ** for Fedora
        $su

     ** for Ubuntu 
        $sudo su

3> in Makefile
     set the "MODE = STA" in Makefile and chose the TARGET to Linux by set "TARGET = LINUX"
     define the linux kernel source include file path LINUX_SRC
     modify to meet your need.

4> in os/linux/config.mk 
     define the GCC and LD of the target machine
     define the compiler flags CFLAGS
     modify to meet your need.

    ** Build for being controlled by NetworkManager or wpa_supplicant wext functions
       Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y'.
       => #>cd wpa_supplicant-x.x
       => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d

    ** Build for being controlled by WpaSupplicant with Ralink Driver
       Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n'.
       => #>cd wpa_supplicant-0.5.7
       => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dralink -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d

5>  compile driver source code
    $make

=======================================================================
Install Instructions:  
================================    
1> load driver
   $make install    

2> plug in USB dongle.  

But I'm a total newbie, I want to learn how Linux works but I don't want to do bad things, so I found some help in this topic http://askubuntu.com/questions/102956/how-do-i-install-an-asus-usb-n53-wifi-adapter

After following these instructions I found myself stuck at the 7th step "Install the module".

I'm getting those errors :

      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Wrap: allocate %d bytes memory failure.
      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Wrap: allocate %d bytes memory failur

      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Unwrap: allocate %d bytes memory failur
      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Unwrap: allocate %d bytes memory failur

gned int’ [-Wformat=]
   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s unable to alloc memory for measure report buffe

   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s unable to alloc memory for measure report buffe

   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION_
                                   ^
   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION_

/home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4926:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, _
                                                                     ^
/home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4926:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 , size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258 : la recette pour la cible « /home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o » a échouée
make[2]: *** [/home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Erreur 1
Makefile:1403 : la recette pour la cible « _module_/home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux » a échouée
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/lionel/Téléchargements/Linux/2011_1003_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic »
Makefile:243 : la recette pour la cible « LINUX » a échouée
make: *** [LINUX] Erreur 2
```

Sorry for the long post, I didn't know what to show for you to help me, whatsmore I couldn't show you all...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Linux 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
```

`lsusb` for the wi-fi key

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0b05:180b ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
```

Hey chili, thanks for your answer!

I tried what you told me to do but I've got some trouble..

I wanted to try my wireless so I plugged the USB key and after Ubuntu has detected it, an error occured, asking me to report it.

When I unplugged it my pc froze and I had to shut down manually.

Ever since, everytime I plug it, I can't exit terminal or other windows and have to shutdown manually. When in terminal a warning appeared :

/home/lionel/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c: In function ‘TxPktClassification’:
/home/lionel/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:1085:4: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
    && (TxFrameType == TX_LEGACY_FRAME)

I don't know if it's linked to my problem.

I think (I say think because the light of the key didnt light on) managed to connect to the wi-fi with it but I can't do it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that, with a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

You wireless should now be working.

When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, recompile:

```
cd Netgear-A6210
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

In order to minimize conflict between the internal wireless and the USB, I suggest that you blacklist its driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath9k"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: Hi chili thanks for your answer, I edited my post to tell you what happened when I tried your method

Comment: Please unplug the device and then run the second sequence of commands. Note any errors and post them here and give me the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com If there is no error (warnings are OK), shut the computer down, insert the device and restart.

Comment: Hi again, I ran the second sequence and the same warning appeared (written at the bottom when I edited) there : http://paste.ubuntu.com/23251812

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Remember warnings are (probably) OK. If you avoid unplugging and re-plugging the USB wireless by booting with it already plugged in, is there still a freeze-up?

Comment: Wow! I booted with it and a new wi-fi network appeared like I got once (MediaTek 802.11acWLAN) and it's working. At the risk of sounding dumb, (I know it's not important at all but I have a doubt) the light from the usb key is off so is this network from my usb card? Sorry for this dumb question, I think you solved my problem thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to turn off the computer and it blocks at the last part with the logo Ubuntu when the key is still plugged so I've to turn it off manually but it's no big deal, thanks again

Comment: You said, "...is this network from my usb card?" Do you have another wireless device? If so, why do you need the USB? The driver for any internal device is probably conflicting and should be blacklisted. Please explain.

Comment: Hi chili. Yes, sorry for not mentioning that, I thought it'd have changed anything... I have a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter since I have bought the computer but it can't handle 5GHz Wi-FI. The campus where I'm going to study is only working with 5GHz Wi-Fi that's why I need my USB card to work

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: I executed the last sequence, I still have to plug my key before turning on the computer otherwise it doesn't work but when I put it before launching it works. In both methods I get an error message asking me to report it.  However I don't have to turn off my computer manually anymore! You're amazing chili